# JavaScript replace

Tags: javascript, html, dom, text, replace

I'm doing something like:

```
<p>SQL</p>
<p>sql</p>
<p>sQl</p>
<p>SqL</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
 var p = ps[i];
 p.childNodes[0].nodeValue.replace(/sql/gi, 'VB.NET');
 p = null;
}
</script>
```

But it's not replacing the text. What's wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: It is working, but you are not setting the value to anything.

Answer (score 4):

replace is **not** a mutator method.

```
el.nodeValue = el.nodeValue.replace(/regex/,'something');
```

use it like so...

[**remember to google.. surprise!**](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=+site:stackoverflow.com+javascript+replace+doesnt+work)

Comment: @thomas: Hey, your question is already rank 4 over at Google with meder's search terms ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
p.childNodes[0].nodeValue = p.childNodes[0].nodeValue.replace(/sql/gi, 'VB.NET');
```

or

```
p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/sql/gi, 'VB.NET');
```

Comment: Caution with use of innerHTML as it's still not officially part of the dom (although it should).

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the replacement back into the `p` element.

Also remember that `alert` is your friend. See what's in `p.childNodes[0].nodeValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 p.childNodes[0].nodeValue=p.childNodes[0].nodeValue.replace(/sql/gi, 'VB.NET');

Answer (score 0):

I believe replace, here, is simply returning the value (it's been a while).

Have you tried:

```
p.childNodes[0].nodeValue = p.childNodes[0].nodeValue.replace(/sql/gi, 'VB.NET');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pull that out into a function in the documents head, then call the method before the closing body tag. This will ensure that the document logs before the js executes:

```
// head
<script type='text/javasript'>
function changeText() {
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for(var i = 0; i<ps.length; i++) {
var node = ps[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue.toLowerCase();
node = node.replace('sql', 'VB.NET');
ps[i].childeNodes[0].nodeValue = node;
}
}
</script>
// Before the closing body tag
<script type='text/javascript'>changeText();</script>
```

You could also using jQuery, here's a find / replace approach, [Find & replace jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233922/find-replace-jquery)